# Async programming in Python with Dask

Tags: python, asynchronous, celery, dask, nonblocking

is there a way to implement the below example in dask?

```py
import time

from celery import Celery

app = Celery('celery_blog', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0', backend='redis://localhost:6379/0')


@app.task
def sl():
    time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sleeper = sl.delay()
    print('submitted')
    print(f"sleeper done: {sleeper.ready()}")
    time.sleep(2)
    print(f"sleeper done: {sleeper.ready()}")
```

looking at http://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/asynchronous.html it seems to me that all of the examples need to `await` the background task in order for the task to even get started, however, await blocks. On the other hand, in the *Use Cases* it says that this can be used instead of `Celery` for non-blocking behaviour. Non of the examples I could find showed something like the `Celery` snippet. I think that I'm missing a crucial puzzle piece. So if you could show me how to get that done or point me to a helpful link I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2016/09/13/dask-and-celery

Comment: That is a specific example, but if you want the async workflow in general, you want the [futures](https://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client.html#concurrent-futures) interface.

Comment: For the record, await does not "block". It suspends execution of your coroutine, so that whatever you are awaiting is started and the event loop will come back and return control to your coroutine when whatever you're awaiting on is finished.

Answer (score 0):

As @mdurant says in the comments you're probably looking for the futures interface to Dask.  See https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/futures.html

```
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client()

future = client.submit(function, *args, **kwargs)
future.result()  # block then get result
```